# Determine a decomposition of the Grötzsch graph into smallest possible number of paths.

Tags: graph-theory

Here is the interesting challenge problem from my graph theory professor.

> Find a decomposition of the Grötzsch graph into smallest possible number of paths.  Give a justification why this is as small as possible.

I found the longest path in Grötzsch graph, which contains 8 edges and 9 vertices.  I believe this is the good start to determine the smallest number of paths, but I'm stuck, and I ran out of ideas for this problem.

Any suggestion or comments?

Comment: Try imposing an orientation of the graph based on its coloring number, in the style of the Gallai-Roy theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Grötzsch graph (the Mycielskian of $C_5$) has 6 odd vertices: each vertex
except the "original" $C_5$ vertices has odd degree. Since each path in a decomposition
adds 2 edges to each of its vertices except its endpoints, there must be at least 3 paths.
Labeling the vertices as $v_0,\ldots,v_4$ (original vertices), $u_0,\ldots,u_4$ and $w$ a
possible path decomposition into 3 paths is
$wu_0v_4v_3v_2v_1v_0u_4$, $u_0v_1u_2wu_1v_0v_4u_3$ and $u_1v_2u_3wu_4v_3u_2$.

Comment: User @RobertMeade has pointed out that the three paths above account for only $19=7+6+6$ of the twenty edges of the Grötzsch graph.  I've located an illustration of the Grötzsch graph with vertex labelling similar to what you've described, but the "original vertices" are $u_1,\ldots,u_5$ and the odd degree vertices are $v_1,\ldots,v_5$ and $w$.  Because of this notational discrepancy, I wouldn't want to add it directly to your Answer without additional edits.  Perhaps you can take another look and advise if you prefer to make changes or have a separate Answer posted below with fixes.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The $u_3$ at the end of the second path was missing. It is fixed now. Thanks.